# jQuery submit preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I load a page from example.com on port 80, then from the loaded page, submit a form to the same server on a different port (as defined in the form action attribute).

(html)

```
<form id="enabledForm" action="http://example.com:39991/updateEnabled" method="POST">
```

(javascript)

```
 $('#enabledForm').submit()
```

This works fine and the data is delivered as expected to the form action url, ***but the browser is redirected to the address of the POST request instead of staying on the requesting page.***

If I use

```
$('#enabledForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$('#enabledForm').submit(function (event) {
    return false;
});
```

then ***the server receives no data*** but the page is not redirected.
if I add an alert within the event handler then the alert is not shown.

```
$('#enabledForm').submit(function (event) {
    alert('inside submit event handler');
    return false;
});
```

Clearly I'm soing something wrong but after hours of headbanging and trying everything I can think of I'm stuck.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basic options here:

- Have the server return a `204 No Content` response and forget about using JS entirely
- Prevent the submission of the form with JS and send the data to the URL with Ajax instead

---

[No content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.5):

> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent.

How you set the HTTP response status code depends on your server side language / framework. For example:

In Catalyst it would be something like:

```
$c->response->status(204);
```

In PHP it would be:

```
http_response_code(204);
```

---

There are *many* Ajax tutorials out there, so I'm not going to provide another one. The jQuery documentation has [a detailed section on Ajax](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Note that since you are working across origins (different ports), you will need to circumvent the Same Origin Policy. The standard way to do that is with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 0):

Sending a form would automatically change your browser URL (and refresh view).You should use an Ajax request to send informations to your server and eventually retrieve completion (success, error, informations...).

Extract your inputs' values to an object via Jquery and send your request via [Jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [Jquery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$('#enabledForm').submit(function (event) {
  //Prevent natual post
  event.preventDefault();

  //Retrieve inputs values
  var data = {}
  $('#enabledForm input,textarea').each(function(index){
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });

  //Send request
  $.post('http://example.com:3999/updateEnabled',data,function(response){
    //Parse response if you want to inform user about success of operation
  });
});
```

I don't know if `val()` is usable with all of yout inputs, but it's easy to adapt...